# ApplicationPreparedEvent with Spring Boot not works

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I trie to run class when application start :

```
@Component
public class BoostrapListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationPreparedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationPreparedEvent applicationPreparedEvent) {
        System.out.println("ApplicationListener Invoked At Spring Container Startup");
    }

}


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        BoostrapListener bean = app.getBean(BoostrapListener.class);
        app.addApplicationListener(bean);
    }
}
```

The BoostrapListener class is never call ..

Can you help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ApplicationPreparedEvent` is invoked *very early* in the lifecycle of the application. We haven't even fully processed the configuration at this point so we couldn't see that bean definition of yours.

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners) gives you a hint but we can do a better job there so I've created [#5061](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5061)

Comment: Thanks Stephane. I just use ApplicationReadyEvent and it works !

Answer (score 0):

maybe use `spring.factories`

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=\
com.boot.example.listener.CustomerListener1
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.