# ApplicationEvent in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, events

I am currently upgrading a spring boot 2 application to spring boot 3. The application uses `EventListener` in some testcases, to prepare testdata. This looks roughly like this:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "...")
@Import(TestConfig.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("Testprofile")
public class Test {
  @Test
  public void test() {...}
}

@TestConfiguration
@Profile("Testprofile")
class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<ApplicationPreparedEvent> setupBean() {...}
}
```

Prior to the update this worked well. Now, the method `setupBean` is called but the `ApplicationListener` bean itself does not get called. I tried to switch the mechanism to an `@EventListener` annotated Method. This had no effect.

I tried to move the code into the production part of the software and had the same issue there: the `@Bean` method gets called, the `ApplicationListener#onApplicationEvent` method does not.

I have not found a hint as to a change within this mechanism.

What do I miss?

---

Edit:
I did a before/after comparison and it seems the `ApplicationPreparedEvent` is no longer being sent. Changing the listener to `ApplicationStartedEvent` works.

Is this supposed to be like this? Why no longer fire an eventtype that was previously fired under similar circumstances?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ApplicationPreparedEvent with Spring Boot not works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115301/applicationpreparedevent-with-spring-boot-not-works) It doesn't tell you a difference between Spring Boot 2 and 3 but you might want to use `ApplicationReadyEvent` instead.

Comment: It looks like your event is fired before the listener is registered. You might need to use `SpringApplication#addListener` to register it from your `main` manually. See also [this](https://medium.com/@truongbui95/spring-boots-application-events-36ebe09e9313)

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I did set a breakpoint with the ApplicationEventpublisher and I cannot see any event of that type being published. Basically, if this is the reason, it is to say "the event is never published, because the publisher itself is not ready to do any work".  Seems like a bug to me? Also, it _did_ work in Spring Boot 2, so I would expect some prominent warning if the default behaviour changed.

Comment: I don't know where this change come from but did you try using `addListener` in your main (not using `@Bean`) as shown [here](https://medium.com/@truongbui95/spring-boots-application-events-36ebe09e9313)